# Get client timezone information in server

Tags: c#

I have a web api project. I need to know the timezone from where I recieve calls to my apis. I have a method which expects a DateTime object as a parameter. I searched if I can somehow get the timezone information from this but apparently it can't be done. For some reason I cant pass the timezone information from client side. Can this be done? Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: So you want client information on the server without sending client information to the server?

Comment: if you know the datetime parameter time in UTC, you can compare the time to get the timezone.

Comment: You can use online services that gives timezone of the IP that you supply in request

Comment: @Jamiec If I am calling the api from a c# application I can send an object of type TimeZoneInfo. But I can't be sure who uses my application and which technologies they will be using. I don't have a requirement to restrict passing timezone info in the request.

Answer (score 4):

Get the Ip Address of your request i.e. `Request.UserHostAddress` and call this api-

> http://ip-api.com/json/yourIpAddress

this will give you all the information as json response like

```
{
"as": "AS24560 Bharti Airtel Ltd., Telemedia Services",
"city": "Lucknow",
"country": "India",
"countryCode": "IN",
"isp": "Airtel Broadband",
"lat": 26.85,
"lon": 80.9167,
"org": "Airtel Broadband",
"query": "122.160.15.23",
"region": "UP",
"regionName": "Uttar Pradesh",
"status": "success",
"timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
"zip": "226010"
}
```